# Quelle est la traduction la plus courante de "so", quand on l'utilise comme adverbe d'intensité ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, choix-de-mot

Je traduis *so* comme *si* depuis plusieurs années, et je m'inquiète parce que je ne vois jamais le mot *si* utilisé de cette manière, ou du moins très rarement.

Est-ce que le mot *tellement* est la traduction la plus courante de *so*, plutôt que *si* ?

Par exemple:

> He is so nice  --> Il est si gentil / il est tellement gentil

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence ?

Comment: Dans les constructions des blagues genre  «Il est **si/tellement** laid **que** même son chien ne joue pas avec lui»,  j’aurais cru que «tellement» sonne mieux que «si», mais Serge Gainsbourg préférait «SI» dans [«Elle est si »](http://www.metrolyrics.com/elle-est-si-lyrics-gainsbourg-serge.html) et en plus, le seul exemple de «tellement» dans cette chanson a plutôt le sens de «so much» que «so».  Donc, *so much for what I was thinking* !

Comment: The answer don't seem to cover that, but nowadays, nobody says "Il est si gentil". Instead, you'll hear "*Il est **trop** gentil*", "*Il est **super** gentil*", or sometimes "*Il est **tellement** gentil*". People are giving you literal answers, but in French, we'll say something closer to "He's really nice" than to "He's so nice".

Comment: I can't stress this enough, if I were you I'd take the answers with a grain of salt. If you say "*Il est si gentil*" in a verbal conversation with French speakers, you'll sound like a textbook, it'll be obvious that you're not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no big difference in usage or meaning.  For example the two phrases "Il est si mignon" or "il est tellement mignon" ("he's so cute") have both around 150,000 results on Google. People have marginal preferences based on what rolls off the tongue better for them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

There is no big difference but *Il est si gentil* would be more common than *Il est tellement gentil*.

However, I'd rather translate it by:

> — Qu'est-ce qu'il est gentil !

or simply:

> — Qu'il est gentil !

Comment: Pour moi, cela serait plutôt la traduction de: _— How nice he is!_

Comment: @mouviciel Oui mais *He is so nice!* me semble suffisamment proche de *How nice he is!* pour le suggérer comme traduction.

Comment: @jlliagre can you comment on the comment just placed on the original post by Teleporting Goat? I don't know what to think, in contrast with your answer, when you're both from France.

Comment: The is no real difference between @TeleportingGoat opinion and mine. I agree with him about the fact the accepted answer support not very idiomatic expressions. One issue is your question was "which one is better" while both *si* and *tellement* were more anglicisms than anything. My suggestions are just slightly formal spoken French while TG's ones are more on the colloquial side, but both are idiomatic. *Il est trop joli* is now extremely common, elderly people are sometimes still shocked because *trop* is normally negative, but it is now accepted spoken French by most people.

Answer (score 1):

Vous pouvez tout simplement traduire par "très" en disant "il est très gentil". En général, tout dépend de la phrase entière comment elle est composée. Veuillez poster toute la phrase à traduire pour essayer d'avoir la meilleur traduction possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with *so* is that it has many different usages, as an intensifier, as a comparison etc. and each have their own French translation.

**Ainsi**, j'ai décidé de partir - "So I decided to leave"

Je n'ai pas mangé, **alors** il est difficile de me concentrer - "I didn't eat, so it's difficult to concentrate"

To your original example, I used and heard *si* all the time when I lived in France. However, I would say that *tellement* is perhaps more of a proper usage, and *si* is more largo.

Comment: Yes, I am aware *so* is translated many ways, I am only talking about *so* as an intensifier.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Les autres réponses me semblent complètement à côté de la plaque, y compris la réponse acceptée. Tu dis "*Je m'inquiète parce que je ne vois jamais le mot si utilisé de cette manière*", et tu as raison de t'inquiéter, quasiment personne ne dit ça.

Il y a une différence entre **une traduction exacte du concept transmis par une expression**, et **l'expression qu'un français dit dans le même contexte**. Je pense qu'il est beaucoup plus important de donner ce qu'un français dirait, plutôt qu'une traduction fidèle mais que personne n'utilise.

En français on utilise très peu *si*, autant quand la proposition est seule ("*Il est si gentil*") que quand elle a une subordonnée ("Il est si gentil *que j'ai envie de l'aider*").

Quand il y a une subordonnée, dans le langage courant, on utilise *tellement*. Et on utilise tout simplement plus cette construction sans subordonnée, sauf dans un cas : ça m'arrive de dire "*Ce film, il était tellement bien !!*", mais je vois ça presque comme un anglicisme. À force de lire et d'entendre de l'anglais, on adopte les mêmes constructions de phrases et les mêmes idées, donc c'est naturel de chercher à exprimer en français des concepts qu'on a l'habitude de lire et d'entendre en anglais. Mais ce n'est *plus* idiomatique pour un français d'utiliser *si* comme intensif. En tout cas plus maintenant, dans le langage courant.

Donc si on ne recherche pas la traduction *exacte*, mais juste ce qu'un francophone dirait dans cette phrase, je recommande plutôt :

> Il est **trop** gentil !
>
> Il est **super** gentil !

C'est ce qu'on utilise pour intensifier *très*, comme en anglais on utilise *so* pour intensifier *very*. Je pense que c'est ces mots là que tu cherchais, plutôt que la différence entre *si* et *tellement*.

J'espère que ça répond à ta question. J'espère aussi que ça ne te dérange pas de lire une réponse en français, si il y a des passages difficiles je peux les traduire.